# Why is an implicit extern declaration invalid if there is a prior static declaration?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, linkage

Consider the following example program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static int n = 123;
extern int n;

int main(void) { printf("n is %d\n", n); return 0; }
```

It compiles successfully with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic myprog.c`. `n` has static linkage according to C99 § 6.2.2 *Linkages of identifiers*, part 4:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

Now remove `extern`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static int n = 123;
int n;

int main(void) { printf("n is %d\n", n); return 0; }
```

This program does not compile. GCC gives this error:

```
myprog.c:4:5: error: non-static declaration of ‘n’ follows static declaration
    4 | int n;
      |     ^
myprog.c:3:12: note: previous definition of ‘n’ was here
    3 | static int n = 123;
      |
```

Why does this error occur? I thought that the `int n;` in the second program is supposed to be equivalent to `extern int n;`. From the C99 standard, § 6.2.2 *Linkages of identifiers*, part 5:

> If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.

Comment: " I thought that the int n; in the second program is supposed to be equivalent to extern int n;" But it is not. The first passage you quote applies to declarations with `extern` specified explicitly, and does not apply to declarations with no `extern`, so they are not equivalent for this reason alone. They are also not equivalent because `int n;` is a *tentative definition* and `extern int n;` isn't.

Answer (score 3):

You've already found the relevant parts in the standard. §4 says that if you declare it `extern` and there's already an internal linkage variable declared, then the linkage of your `extern` turns internal too - so it will refer to the same variable, just as if you had written `static int n;` twice.

These rules are kind of muddy and oddball features like this are obsolete. I don't know the historical reasons why it's there in the first place.

> 6.11.2 Linkages of identifiers
> Declaring an identifier with internal linkage at file scope without the `static` storage class specifier is an obsolescent feature.

In the latter case you specify no linkage so it's a tentative definition. As per your quoted part in §5, it gets external linkage and then you get a naming collision with the internal linkage identifier in the same translation unit, hence the compiler error.

Comment: Which document does the quote come from?

Comment: "I don't know the historical reasons why it's there in the first place." — The C89 and C99 rationale documents mention something about allowing one-pass compilation.

Comment: @Flux: Many of the rules about `extern` date to a time where different compilers handled things differently, and the goal was to write the Standard so as to be compatible with code written to fit different compilers' semantics.  IMHO, the Standard should have said that `extern int foo[] = {1,2,3};` would be equivalent to `extern int foo[3];`, with the initializer used only to compute the array size, but it gives the presence of the initializer priority over `extern` in deciding linkage.